# Overriding UIAlertView (View background)

Tags: customization, subclass, uialertview, overriding

I am overriding the UIAlertView class with something similar seen in this tutorial
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-uialertview-custom-graphics/
So I am overriding the drawRect...

My problem is not actually customizing the alert itself, but rather the view background color behind the UIAlertView itself right now it is the standard black gradient that all UIAlertViews have... Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took this approach and seems to work... In layoutSubview I am looping over the superviews subviews

```
    for (UIView*superSub in self.superview.subviews) {
    if ([superSub isMemberOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
        superSub.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:30/255. green:21/255. blue:4/255. alpha:1];
        superSub.alpha = 0.77;
    }
}
```